# Is there an open source javascript rich text editor similar to gmail's?

Tags: javascript, jquery, richtextbox

I've looked at free javascript html editors, and I haven't found any that I feel handle links intuitively.  I like the way the gmail editor does it (also the same way blogger.com) does it.

Does anyone know if there is an open source editor that handles linking that way? Jquery would be preferable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use TinyMCE myself as Banzor suggests but here are a few other alternatives eash with their own strengths:

- WYMeditor - http://www.wymeditor.org/
- CKEditor - http://ckeditor.com/
- FCKeditor - http://drupal.org/project/fckeditor

Answer (score 7):

gmail uses the open source closure-libary (made by google). Some documentation can be found here:

https://developers.google.com/closure/library/

An example of an editor created with the closure-libary, much similar to the gmail editor (e.g. the link part), can be found here:

https://google.github.io/closure-library/source/closure/goog/demos/editor/editor.html

Answer (score 3):

I use TinyMCE. It is probably the most powerful JavaScript version and it has really clean markup! The entire UI is customizable too. They have alot of info on the [TinyMCE website](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)

Here is the jQuery version: [TINYMCE plugin](http://dev.jquery.com/wiki/Plugins/tinyMCE)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Dennis,

But recently there is a very well customized feature for gmail!

[New gmail text editing options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6A61.jpg)

Hence is there a simple code like above and also can recognize right to left and left to right languages automatically.